# Creating custom pages for new users automatically

Tags: users, signup

I am new here and I have a few questions about Wordpress functionality or functionality that I can add through plugins.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. When a new user signs up, a new page is automatically created, with the page name being the person's user name
2. I would like to beable to add custom sign up fields, and call to it on their new page. For example "Favorite food"
3. On this new page, I would like to make a call to the new field. I would like to show one sentence on the page. For example "My favorite food is potatoes."

I have searched and tried a few plugins, but to no avail. Any suggestions or any tutorials to point me in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Thank you

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register When a new user is added to the database you can generate a new page and do everyhing you want.

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) action for this task. This action fires immediately after a new user is registered.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    //Your Code

}
```

Comment: I'm almost finished, for anyone who is wondering: I used this to display meta information from the theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta, I put the example there in a custom page template 

Then, in regards to adding a new page, I read up on wp_insert_post, and inserted what I found into the //your code section using the of what Ranuka gave.